# Full Calendar (TimeGridWeek) - Slot duration set to 1 minute but should still display whole day

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have recently chosen to switch from using Google timeline charts to Full Calendar to give my time tracking a better feeling, but I have run into a problem i can't seem to solve.

**What i am trying to:**
I am trying to make the full calendar (In React) display events with 1 minute's precision since some of the tracked times is down to a minute in lenght. But even though it should display the slots with 1 minutes precision it should still show full day (almost without vertical scroll). So in other words: slots only lasting 1 or a few minutes gets crammed together tightly instead of the calendar expanding like crazy vertically.

**What i have done so far:**
So far I have tried almost every combination (I feel like). I have set slotDuration to "00:01:00" (One minute) and now the calendar is displaying a kilometer long scroll.

It doesn't seem like in the documentation that there is a way to "zoom out" and view more of the day instead of being stuck with kilometers of scrolling.

**My settings are as followed:**

```
<FullCalendar
                            ref={cal}
                            plugins={[timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                            initialView="timeGridWeek"
                            weekends={false}
                            locale={svLocale}
                            direction="ltr"
                            height="800px"
                            firstDay={1}
                            slotDuration="00:01:00"
                            slotLabelInterval={{hours: 1}}
                            slotMinTime="05:00"
                            scrollTime="05:00"
                            allDaySlot={false}
                            headerToolbar={{
                                start: '',
                                center: '',
                                end: ''
                            }}
                            footerToolbar={{
                                start: '',
                                center: '',
                                end: 'today prevButton,nextButton'
                            }}
                            slotLabelFormat={{
                                hour: "2-digit",
                                minute: "2-digit",
                                omitZeroMinute: false,
                                meridiem: "short"
                            }}
                            eventTimeFormat={{
                                hour: "2-digit",
                                minute: "2-digit",
                                meridiem: false,
                                hour12: false
                            }}
                            nowIndicator={true}
                            events={calendarData}
                            eventOverlap={false}
                            slotEventOverlap={false}
                            eventClick={
                                function (arg) {
                                    setSelectedCalendarItem(arg.event.title.substring(arg.event.title.length, arg.event.title.indexOf('#')).substring(1));
                                    setMousePosition({ top: arg.jsEvent.clientY, left: arg.jsEvent.clientX });
                                }
                            }
                            eventContent={
                                function (arg) {
                                    return (
                                        <Tooltip title={arg.event.title} arrow>
                                            <div className='fc-event-main-frame'>
                                                {arg.timeText && <div className='fc-event-time'>{arg.timeText}</div>}
                                                <div className='fc-event-title-container'>
                                                    <div className='fc-event-title fc-sticky'>
                                                        {arg.event.title || <React.Fragment>&nbsp;</React.Fragment>}
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </Tooltip>
                                    );
                                }
                            }
                            customButtons={{
                                prevButton: {
                                    text: "Förra",
                                    click: handleDisplayPreviousWeek
                                },
                                nextButton: {
                                    text: "Nästa",
                                    click: handleDisplayNextWeek
                                }
                            }}
                        />
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: `t doesn't seem like in the documentation that there is a way to "zoom out"`...that's correct. There is no solution currently except to zoom your browser, AFAIK. Perhaps you can support a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features).

Comment: @ADyson - No, i can't seem to find anything about it too. I have now made a feature request which can be found here: [Feature request on github](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/6762).